# Why does the 'mypy' module report an error when I implement a method in the class and assign a reference to a method in a class by a factory method

Tags: python

I encounter a problem when I use the `mypy` module to check my code. The problem is demonstrated in the code as below:

```
from typing import Callable
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class A(metaclass = ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class B(A):

    def __init__(self, shouldUseG: bool):
        super().__init__()
        self.foo: Callable = self._factory_to_generate_function(shouldUseG) # line 17

    def _factory_to_generate_function(self, shouldUseG: bool) -> Callable:

        read_data_function: Callable = {True:  self.g,
                                        False: self.h}[shouldUseG]
        return read_data_function

    def foo(self): # line 25
        pass

    def g(self):
        print('This is g.')

    def h(self):
        print('This is h.')
```

Class `B` is a subclass of Class `A`. For Class `B` to inherit Class `A`, the method `foo` must be implemented in Class `B`. But the reference of `foo` depends on the value of the variable `shouldUseG` in Class B. So I create a method `_factory_to_generate_function` to determine the reference of the method `foo`. And I also declare the method `foo` in class `B` in line 25.

My question is when I run the `mypy` module to check this code, it will return the following error for line 17:

```
test.py:17: error: Cannot assign to a method  [assignment]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

And I find that this error won't occur if I do not declare the method `foo` in line 25. I can't understand why this will cause the error. Could anyone kindly explain it to me? And does that mean that the abstract method can be implemented in a way like in line 17 so I do not have to declare the method again in a scenario like this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `Cannot assign to a method`. mypy doesn't want you assigning to methods. (Sure, it's something you *can* do, that works fine at runtime, but so are like half of all static typing errors. Python static typing is deliberately more restrictive than what works at runtime. That's what you signed up for.)

Comment: You should have two separated classes anyway, one that uses `h` and one that uses `g`.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you very much for your reply. I wonder why assigning to methods is not favored by mypy. Is it because it is a bad coding style or because it may cause any any potential problems? Hope I am not asking a big question.

Comment: @thomas_chang: It breaks overriding, for one thing.